# How to use a C# class library from an IronPython app in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, ironpython, class-library

I am a new user of Visual Studio, and I am trying to figure out how to load a C# class library built as part of a solution from an IronPython project in the same solution.

Basically, I am trying to do the scenario in *[How to debug a class library in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027698/how-to-debug-a-class-library-in-visual-studio)* but using an IronPython script instead of the console application.

Normally outside a solution I would use:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile(fname)
```

What should I put in for `fname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure the `SearchPath` directory

[image]

and then:

```
clr.AddReference("NameOfAssembly")
```

or you could also specify the full path:

```
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(@"c:\work\someproject\bin\debug\NameOfAssembly.dll")
```

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2007/09/25/5130072.aspx) describing the different functions for loading assemblies in IronPython.